# iOS simple TCP connection example

Tags: ios, tcp

Does anyone know of a simple TCP example for iOS devices so I can send a string to a server. I've had a look at the following library https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket but it seems very verbose.

All I really want is to have a simple way of connecting to an IP address & port number and sending a string of data to this address. Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for iOS TCP-server or iOS TCP-client example? Or both? Anyway: Robbies CocoaAsyncSocket is almost an industry standard - at least it's worth to check it out thoroughly.

Comment: TCP-Client so I can send data to a server and then have my Unity app read from it. Am I write in thinking that it will be ok for my iOS app to send data to the server whilst running in the background?

Comment: Sending data in backgound is a bit tricky if you want your app to be published in the App Store. Only certain categories of apps are allowed to do some real work in background (such as VoIP & navigation-related apps). I'm not sure if Apple had changed this conditions recently.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**SocketConnectionVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SocketConnectionVC : UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate>
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

    NSInputStream   *inputStream;
    NSOutputStream  *outputStream;

    NSMutableArray  *messages;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ipAddressText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *portText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dataToSendText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *dataRecievedTextView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *connectedLabel;


@end
```

**SocketConnectionVC.m**

```
#import "SocketConnectionVC.h"

@interface SocketConnectionVC ()

@end

@implementation SocketConnectionVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _connectedLabel.text = @"Disconnected";
}

- (IBAction) sendMessage {

    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"msg:%@", _dataToSendText.text];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];

}

- (void) messageReceived:(NSString *)message {

    [messages addObject:message];

    _dataRecievedTextView.text = message;
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    NSLog(@"stream event %lu", streamEvent);

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            _connectedLabel.text = @"Connected";
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            if (theStream == inputStream)
            {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                NSInteger len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
                {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0)
                    {
                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                            [self messageReceived:output];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            NSLog(@"Stream has space available now");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
             NSLog(@"%@",[theStream streamError].localizedDescription);
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            _connectedLabel.text = @"Disconnected";
            NSLog(@"close stream");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }

}

- (IBAction)connectToServer:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Setting up connection to %@ : %i", _ipAddressText.text, [_portText.text intValue]);
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) _ipAddressText.text, [_portText.text intValue], &readStream, &writeStream);

    messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self open];
}

- (IBAction)disconnect:(id)sender {

    [self close];
}

- (void)open {

    NSLog(@"Opening streams.");

    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;

    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];

    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [outputStream open];
    [inputStream open];

    _connectedLabel.text = @"Connected";
}

- (void)close {
    NSLog(@"Closing streams.");
    [inputStream close];
    [outputStream close];
    [inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream setDelegate:nil];
    [outputStream setDelegate:nil];
    inputStream = nil;
    outputStream = nil;

    _connectedLabel.text = @"Disconnected";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**snapshot for ui of this SocketConnectionVC**
[image]

**and Follow these steps**

```
1- input the ip on ipAdress textfield
2- input the port on port textfield
3- press connect button
4- (make sure the ip address and port is correct and the open of stream is fine. you can show the status of stream on console of Xcode)
5- input data to send to server
6- press send button
7- you can show the received message from server on the text view above connect button
```

Comment: i got conection refused message

Comment: check if server is running, and make sure if ip address and port is correct, and the open of stream is fine, you can show the status of stream on console of Xcode

Comment: Perfect example works well, but using this code i am unable to send data to other device.

Answer (score 12):

@Mohamad Chami's example was really great, tried to write a Swift version of it
[GitHubLink](https://github.com/anoop4real/SocketSwiftSample)

```
class SocketDataManager: NSObject, StreamDelegate {

    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    var inputStream: InputStream?
    var outputStream: OutputStream?
    var messages = [AnyHashable]()
    weak var uiPresenter :PresenterProtocol!

    init(with presenter:PresenterProtocol){

        self.uiPresenter = presenter
    }
    func connectWith(socket: DataSocket) {

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (socket.ipAddress! as CFString), UInt32(socket.port), &readStream, &writeStream)
        messages = [AnyHashable]()
        open()
    }

    func disconnect(){

        close()
    }

    func open() {
        print("Opening streams.")
        outputStream = writeStream?.takeRetainedValue()
        inputStream = readStream?.takeRetainedValue()
        outputStream?.delegate = self
        inputStream?.delegate = self
        outputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        inputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        outputStream?.open()
        inputStream?.open()
    }

    func close() {
        print("Closing streams.")
        uiPresenter?.resetUIWithConnection(status: false)
        inputStream?.close()
        outputStream?.close()
        inputStream?.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        outputStream?.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        inputStream?.delegate = nil
        outputStream?.delegate = nil
        inputStream = nil
        outputStream = nil
    }

    func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        print("stream event \(eventCode)")
        switch eventCode {
        case .openCompleted:
            uiPresenter?.resetUIWithConnection(status: true)
            print("Stream opened")
        case .hasBytesAvailable:
            if aStream == inputStream {
                var dataBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 1024)
                var len: Int
                while (inputStream?.hasBytesAvailable)! {
                    len = (inputStream?.read(&dataBuffer, maxLength: 1024))!
                    if len > 0 {
                        let output = String(bytes: dataBuffer, encoding: .ascii)
                        if nil != output {
                            print("server said: \(output ?? "")")
                            messageReceived(message: output!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        case .hasSpaceAvailable:
            print("Stream has space available now")
        case .errorOccurred:
            print("\(aStream.streamError?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
        case .endEncountered:
            aStream.close()
            aStream.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
            print("close stream")
            uiPresenter?.resetUIWithConnection(status: false)
        default:
            print("Unknown event")
        }
    }

    func messageReceived(message: String){

        uiPresenter?.update(message: "server said: \(message)")
        print(message)
    }

    func send(message: String){

        let response = "msg:\(message)"
        let buff = [UInt8](message.utf8)
        if let _ = response.data(using: .ascii) {
            outputStream?.write(buff, maxLength: buff.count)
        }

    }

}





class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var socketConnector:SocketDataManager!
    @IBOutlet weak var ipAddressField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var portField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageHistoryView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var connectBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabl: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        socketConnector = SocketDataManager(with: self)
        resetUIWithConnection(status: false)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func connect(){
        //http://localhost:50694/
        guard let ipAddr = ipAddressField.text, let portVal = portField.text  else {
            return
        }
        let soc = DataSocket(ip: ipAddr, port: portVal)
        socketConnector.connectWith(socket: soc)

    }
    @IBAction func send(){
        guard let msg = messageField.text else {
            return
        }
        send(message: msg)
        messageField.text = ""
    }
    func send(message: String){

        socketConnector.send(message: message)
        update(message: "me:\(message)")
    }
}

extension ViewController: PresenterProtocol{

    func resetUIWithConnection(status: Bool){

        ipAddressField.isEnabled = !status
        portField.isEnabled = !status
        messageField.isEnabled = status
        connectBtn.isEnabled = !status
        sendBtn.isEnabled = status

        if (status){
            updateStatusViewWith(status: "Connected")
        }else{
            updateStatusViewWith(status: "Disconnected")
        }
    }
    func updateStatusViewWith(status: String){

        statusLabl.text = status
    }

    func update(message: String){

        if let text = messageHistoryView.text{
            let newText = """
            \(text)            
            \(message)
            """
            messageHistoryView.text = newText
        }else{
            let newText = """
            \(message)
            """
            messageHistoryView.text = newText
        }

        let myRange=NSMakeRange(messageHistoryView.text.count-1, 0);
        messageHistoryView.scrollRangeToVisible(myRange)


    }


}


struct DataSocket {

    let ipAddress: String!
    let port: Int!

    init(ip: String, port: String){        
        self.ipAddress = ip
        self.port      = Int(port)
    }
}
```

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket
Swift Socket library provide you a simple interface for socket based connection.
Refer to this link and below sample.

```js
let client = TCPClient(address: "www.apple.com", port: 80)
switch client.connect(timeout: 1) {
  case .success:
    switch client.send(string: "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" ) {
      case .success:
        guard let data = client.read(1024*10) else { return }

        if let response = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) {
          print(response)
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
  case .failure(let error):
    print(error)
}
```

### Heading

Comment: SwiftSocket did not work for me.  Others suggest that it is out-of-date.  its github issues are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Those who are unable to receive data at the server side:

It is perhaps due to data encoding mechanism. @Mohamad Chami's answer works fine after changing the data encoding mechanism at the `sendMessage` method as follows:

In his example, `NSString` is converted to `NSData` by:

```
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

Change the `NSASCIIStringEncoding` to `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. It is because at server's side (Oracle database server in my case), the data is received in modified UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Ray gives nice example of building custom server using Python + iOS client application. He has very nice set of tutorials on iOS topics - it is worth to visit his site.

Comment: Could iOS app can act as TCP server app,

Comment: Every one is giving the same link which is in python... not expected

Answer (score 0):

```
import Network


@objc protocol TCPConnectionDelegate {
    @objc optional func deviceStatusUpdated(isUpdated:Bool)
    @objc optional func deviceSwitchToNetwork(deviceId:String)
    @objc optional func TcpConnectionState(state:String,ip:String)
}

class TCPConnection:NSObject{

    var delegate:TCPConnectionDelegate?
    var connection: NWConnection?

    final func start(host:NWEndpoint.Host) {
        connection = NWConnection(host: host, port: 1234, using: .tcp)
        connection!.stateUpdateHandler = self.stateDidChange(to:)
        self.setupReceive(on: connection!)
        connection!.start(queue: .main)
        //self.connection = connection
    }
    
    func stateDidChange(to state: NWConnection.State) {
        var ipAddressWithPort = connection!.endpoint.debugDescription
        let ip = ipAddressWithPort.components(separatedBy: ":")
        switch state {
        case .setup:
            break
        case .waiting(let error):
            print("Errrooor",error)
            self.delegate?.TcpConnectionState!(state: error.localizedDescription, ip: ip[0])
        //self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
        case .preparing:
            break
        case .ready:
            print("Readddy",connection?.endpoint.debugDescription)
            
            print("IPAADERESS",ip[0])
            self.delegate?.TcpConnectionState!(state: "Connected",ip: ip[0])
        case .failed(let error):
            print("FAiled",error)
            self.delegate?.TcpConnectionState!(state: error.localizedDescription, ip: ip[0])
        case .cancelled:
            break
        }
      
    }
    
    func setupReceive(on connection: NWConnection) {
        connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 65536) { (data, contentContext, isComplete, error) in
            if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
                
                print("Received:", String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) )
                let stringData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                let data = stringData!.data(using: .utf8)
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
                    
                   
                    
                    
                    print("REsponseeeeData",json)
                }catch{
                    
                }
                
            }
            if isComplete {
                self.connectionDidEnd()
            } else if let error = error {
                self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
            } else {
                self.setupReceive(on: connection)
            }
        }
    }
    var didStopCallback: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil
    private func connectionDidFail(error: Error) {
        print("connection did fail, error: \(error)")
        stop(error: error)
    }

    private func connectionDidEnd() {
        print("connection  did end")
        stop(error: nil)
    }
    private func stop(error: Error?) {
        connection!.stateUpdateHandler = nil
        connection!.cancel()
        if let didStopCallback = didStopCallback {
            self.didStopCallback = nil
            didStopCallback(error)
        }
    }
    
    func sendStreamOriented(connection: NWConnection, data: Data) {
        connection.send(content: data, completion: .contentProcessed({ error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Errrorrrr",error)
                //  self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
            }
        }))
    }
    
    func sendEndOfStream(connection: NWConnection) {
        connection.send(content: nil, contentContext: .defaultStream, isComplete: true, completion: .contentProcessed({ error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Errrorrrr11111",error)
                // self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
            }
        }))
    }
    
    func sendMsg(message: [String:Any]) {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: message, options: .prettyPrinted)
        guard let jsnStr = String(data: json!, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
        print("ekdhkhfkehflhf",jsnStr)
        
        let msg = jsnStr + "\r\n"
        let data: Data? = msg.data(using: .utf8)
        connection!.send(content: data, completion: .contentProcessed { (sendError) in
            if let sendError = sendError {
                print("\(sendError)")
            }
            })
        self.setupReceive(on: connection!)
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        connection!.cancel()
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sample from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TCPTransports/Introduction/Intro.html) shows how to use various Apple APIs to run a TCP connection.

I had try these method to use socket on Mac.

1. [Stream  Socket](https://github.com/yycking/Socket/blob/main/Sources/Socket/StreamSocket.swift)
2. [URLSessionStreamTask  Socket](https://github.com/yycking/Socket/blob/main/Sources/Socket/URLSessionSocket.swift)
3. [NWTCPConnection Socket](https://github.com/yycking/Socket/blob/main/Sources/Socket/NetworkSocket.socket)